# ¿Cómo reemplazar valores de una fila aplicando la función substr?

Tags: r

Buenas lo que deseo es cambiar en mi `data.frame` los valores de mi fila `OBJ` aplicando la función:

```
substr(text,7,stop=gregexpr(',',text,TRUE)[[1]][1]-1)
```

Que me funciona perfecto y hace lo que deseo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se como ejecutar en el `data.frame` esta función y que me devuelva toda las columnas cambiadas:

Lo que me deseo cambiar es

`LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022` por `ABL9011E`.

Answer (score 0):

Al ser R un lenguaje que maneja básicamente vectores y/o todo tipo de arreglos, la mayoría de las funciones son vectorizadas, es decir, entienden los vectores de entrada y la salida es consistente con los mismos. En cuanto a tu pregunta, realmente has resuelto la parte más importante, la duda acerca de como hacer lo mismo con un columna del `data.frame` es fácil de responder: exactamente de la misma forma en que lo has planteado. En tu ejemplo tienes una variable `text` que imaginas que es una cadena, pero en realidad es un vector de tipo caracter con un solo elemento (no hay datos atómicos en R, lo mínimo es un vector con un elemento), por lo que poco importa en este caso si el vector tiene un elemento o mucho, el funcionamiento de `substr` es exactamente el mismo. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
# Armamos un data.frame con 10 filas 
df <- data.frame(OBJ=rep('LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022',10))

# Generamos la nueva columna
df$NEWOBJ <- substr(df$OBJ,7,stop=gregexpr(',',df$OBJ,TRUE)[[1]][1]-1)
df

                                               OBJ   NEWOBJ
1  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
2  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
3  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
4  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
5  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
6  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
7  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
8  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
9  LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
10 LABEL=ABL9011E, CellIndex=212, CGI=36801014B0022 ABL9011E
```

Comment: Gracias amigo era eso lo que me faltaba